# Paint .Net - Resize and edit existing shape (Like Rounded Rectangle)

Tags: paint.net

I am new to Paint.Net and first thing that I would like to learn is how to re-size existing Shape. Please refer below image. Here I have two rectangles in two different layers, I would like to re-size or say change any of their properties (like color).

My understanding is that I need go to their layer first and then click on <kbd>Tools -> "Some Selection Control"</kbd> and then it should allow me to change properties of the rectangle (like size or color). I have already tried all of the existing selection controls but wasn't able to find any control which will let me select that rectangle only and will let me change the properties.
[image]

I searched on Google as well as Paint.Net forums but didn't find any helpful answer.
I have already referred below links

- [Shape Selection Tools](http://www.getpaint.net/doc/latest/ShapeSelectionTools.html)
- [Resize shapes](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/2927-resize-shapes/)

I used to use Photoshop and it was pretty straight forward in Photoshop, in there it would allow you to select existing shape and change its properties easily (like size, color). Just referring Photoshop to explain my question :)

Thanks in advance for your time and help :)

Comment: I know very little of paint, but surely, a simple google search would give you the answer, in some basic tutorial?

Comment: @boblet: I tried Google and even searched all the forums of Paint.Net but wasn't able to find any information. You may have already noticed reference links in my questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paint.net is a basic bitmap-only application without vector tools. When you draw shapes, they are pixel-based and can't be rescaled or reshaped anymore. You should consider using a more sophisticated application, e.g., [RealWorld Paint 2013](http://www.rw-designer.com), [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org), [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/en/) (vector-based), or what have you...

Comment: @TehMacDwag: That explains why I can't find the answer :) Looks like I have to use something else. Thanks.